# Entity Manager per Thread design - how to implement

Tags: spring, hibernate, design-patterns, jpa

I want to know how to implement a JPA EntityManager per user thread design. Since EM are light weight objects, it should not be an overhead to create them per user thread. The problem I want to solve is a single JSP page with multiple (parallel) JSON/AJAX calls to back-end services (via controllers).

I am having an Entity Manager (with persistence context EXTENDED), with Open EM In View Filter. It does work nice, but only when there is one user thread (say, a json call) per page, or in other words when I access em in serial fashion. 
It does not however solve my purpose when I call my services from multiple threads as em instances are shared and I get weird errors (sometimes shared access to collections, and sometimes closed connection, which are expected I believe).

I am using JPA over Spring 3 and hibernate 3.5. I inject an entity manager (extended) into my services as below:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
protected EntityManager em;
```

My readonly service methods are annotated as

```
<tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS"/>
```

All other methods, are annotated as

```
<tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception"/>
```

I want to avoid an application managed em, and hence did not go for injecting a EntityManagerFactory instead.
Also, If I choose to inject EntityManager into spring controller, I will still have issues when same controller is called in parallel from two threads !

Is there an elegant way to achieve a thread safe access to em. I also want to avoid locking any entity objects, which complicates things further.

Since multiple ajax calls from same page is a very common design in modern web - applications, I believe there must be a simple and declarative way of achieving this (without going back to managing hibernate sessions manually with interceptors etc)

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand your problem.

Entity manager per thread is a default behaviour, but you explicitly overrode it with `EXTENDED`. Do you have any specific reason for configuring it as `EXTENDED`? If not, all you need is to remove it:

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;
```

Comment: I have it as EXTENDED to make sure that all lazy associations are loaded without any extra effort. Otherwise I will have to load each one of them (they are many !) manually.... Eg user.organisation, user.roles, event. property etc etc which work seamlessly now.

Comment: @Dilpa: As long as you use access them while processing the request, Open EM in View filter should handle it already.

Comment: In that case, what could be the source of `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` which I get whenever I am loading a lazy association. I do have OEMIV filter in place.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a Thread scope, which is disabled by default (See the section [4.5 Bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)):

> **Thread-scoped beans**
>    As of Spring 3.0, a thread scope is available, but
>   is not registered by default. For more information, see the
>   documentation for [`SimpleThreadScope`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html). For instructions on how to
>   register this or any other custom scope, see Section 4.5.5.2, [“Using a
>   custom scope”.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom-using)

If you activate the scope, you can just define your entitymanagers as `scope=thread`

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about this. Thanks for this. So do you suggest that I make my spring controller registered as thread scope (as opposed to singleton now) ?

Comment: @Dilpa no, I am not *suggesting* that. I have used singleton-scoped entitymanagerfactories for years and hardly ever had problems. But I am providing a possible answer to your question, that's a difference ;-)

Comment: Okay, I will love to give it a try. Could you please elaborate on how can I define my entitymanagers as scope=thread ? or are you 'suggesting' i make my emf as thread scoped ?

Comment: Wont that be a huge strain on my application ?

Comment: @Dilpa I don't think so. You can probably configure the number of threads your application spawns in your app server. In most cases, 10 to 20 threads should be plenty

Answer (score 0):

This is the most standard way of working with EM/Sessions, and there are standard tools like OpenSessionInViewFilter (or Interceptor) which creates a session when HTTP Request comes into your servlet container. 
Or it can be a Spring Transactional support which creates a session with the help of AOP. 
The key point here is to use already existing mechanism or, if you have some extensions, at least copy-paste them.
Spring does this via binding/unbinding the resources to the thread with the help of TransactionSynchronizationManager. You can take a look at Spring sources or [here](http://fisheye.jtalks.org/browse/~br=dionis_branch/Poulpe/poulpe-view/poulpe-web-controller/src/main/java/org/jtalks/poulpe/web/osod/OpenSessions.java?r=89f6148d552fa1e2a5b4e6c34ad2e8237a546c44) is an example of session-per-conversation pattern which also uses the same means to bind resources to threads.